# changing html style with form choice?

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML web page which needs to be modified.

I created a form (dropdown list) on the HTML page to let the user choose the backgroundcolor whether that be yellow, white, etc but here's where the problem comes in when the user picks their choice I don't know how to precisely execute it.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<div>
    <label for=“background”>color of background</label>
    <select name=“background” id=(“background”)>
        <option value=“yellow”>yellow</option>
        <option value=“Orange”>orange</option>
        <option value=“Purple”>purple</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript code (using the jQuery library):

```
$(“#background”).css(“backgroundcolor”, “yellow”):
```

The above only result in only a yellow background.

Is there a way to make this happen based on the choice of the user so as not to hard-code it by setting it only to a specific colour (yellow is this instance)?

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you could find your answer by a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of a select box, you need to change the color of the option elements. Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
   
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('option').css('background-color',this.value);
})
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
<label for=“background”>color of background</label>
<select name=“background” id=“background”>
<option>yellow</option>
<option>orange</option>
<option>purple</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a onChange function on Select Input like this.

```
function changeBackgroundColor(e) {
    var value = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    if(value) {
        $('#background').css('backgroundcolor', value);
    }
} 
$('#background').on('change', changeBackgroundColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div>
<label for=“background”>color of background</label>
<select name=“background” class="set-bg" id=(“background”)>
<option value=“yellow”>yellow</option>
<option value=“Orange”>orange</option>
<option value=“Purple”>purple</option>
</select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(ducument).ready(function(){
        $('.set-bg').change(function(){
            $(“#background”).css(“backgroundcolor”, $(this).val());
        });
    });
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

First Here's my code, and my explanation will follow:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <label for='background'>color of background</label>
        <select name='background' id='background' onclick="changeBackground()">
            <option value='yellow'>yellow</option>
            <option value='orange'>orange</option>
            <option value='purple'>purple</option>
        </select>
     </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeBackground(){
var x = document.getElementById('background').value;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = x;
}
```

So Here's whats happening, I created a function called changeBackground() that when a choice is selected will automatically run. Note: I did change some of the things you had in your body, mainly using ' instead of "

Note: This changes the body color for that session, and does not save it to the html file or css file.

Hope this helps, if you believe this is the right answer, please "check" it!